# Validate clock time with quarters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to match below  in a text box when user entered values.

.00
.25
.50
.75

and 2 specific digits:

[0 to 23].00
[0 to 23].25
[0 to 23].50
[0 to 23].75

for example 1.25, 12.25, 22.50, etc. All above values are **allowed**.
Values like `0`, `7`, `12.18`, `24.00` are **not allowed**.

Currently I am just checking below which will allow any decimal values.

```js
var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode
if (
  (charCode != 46 || $(element).val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
  (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)
) return false;
return true;
```

Comment: Why you're going the `"keydown"` event way? What if someone pastes a value into your input. Makes no sense I believe to go for key events.

Comment: Wait, so `"13.00"` is invalid?

Comment: This is a very confusing way to describe the rules. What if user enters ".2" and goes afk to drink a coffee? Is that value allowed? If not, then how can the user enter ".25". If it *is* allowed, then ... what?

Comment: Why is `"0.25"` not allowed but `".25"` is?

Comment: Roko - my code is there to remove leading 0 so 0.25 is not required. and this is only I am looking for to enter those pattern ...basically its hours in deciaml ...so let say .25 is 15 minutes .50 is 30 minutes and .75 is 45 minutes

Comment: 13.00 is valid. so now lets say it 13.00, 13.25, 13.50, 13.75 these are valid

Comment: @jenkuj but you did not mentioned in your question that 1...23.00 is valid...

Comment: @jenkuj is `.00` valid? (midnight, remember?) Speaking of midnight, then why it's not just `0` valid?

Answer (score 0):

## Validate clock time with quarters

Thanks to the comments section we all realized it's a validation of a *clock* time (question edited to reflect).
Glad to remind here that in such case `.00` or either `0.00` — should be a valid input since it represents **midnight**. And therefore all other integers of full-hour like `1.00` up to `23.00` are **also valid**.

Don't use keyboard Events. As @trincot suggested, if a user enters `".2"` he will no longer be able to finish the desired number (*0.25*) since `".2"` *is* (per your statement) already *invalid*.

Instead, use rather a `"blur"` or some other event. Or you can also use the Input element `pattern` attribute to visually mark the input as *invalid*.

Here's the basic regex to match the desired: a **clock time with quarters**

```
^(\d|[0-1]\d|2[0-3])?\.(00|15|30|45)$
```

or if you use decimals as *hundreds*:

```
^(\d|[0-1]\d|2[0-3])?\.(00|25|50|75)$
```

[Regex101.com demo and explanation](https://regex101.com/r/5sfjN7/1)

---

Example of input [pattern attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern):

```css
input:invalid { background: red; }
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="(\d|[0-1]\d|2[0-3])?\.(00|25|50|75)">
```

Example using [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) ideal for JS validation

```js
const validateNumDec = n => /^(\d|[0-1]\d|2[0-3])?\.(00|25|50|75)$/.test(n);

console.log(".00", validateNumDec(".00")); // true
console.log(".25", validateNumDec(".25")); // true
console.log("13.00", validateNumDec("13.00")); // true
console.log("23.75", validateNumDec("23.75")); // true

console.log("5", validateNumDec("5")); // false
console.log("5.13", validateNumDec("5.13")); // false
console.log("5.13", validateNumDec("23.59")); // false
```

---

#### Final note

One might eventually simply go for `<input type="time"` but as you can see the `step="900"` (`900` seconds being 15 minutes) do work when using i.e: keyboarrd's up/down arrows (15 min jump), but it's not respected in the popup picker — in Chrome browser:

```html
<input type="time" min="00:00" max="18:00" step="900" required>
```

From the MDN documentation about [Using the Step attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#using_the_step_attribute):

> ***Note**:
>
> Using step seems to cause validation to not work properly (as seen in the next section).*

---

Documentation:

- [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)
- [Pattern attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern)

Comment: Thanks a lot Roko C. Buljan, its worked for me.

Comment: Nice, glad to hear. You're very welcome!